# Magento API call 'product_stock.update' not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, magento, soap

im currently working with the magento soap v1 API called from Javascript. 
login, catalog_product.list and other calls work for me, but im having trouble with updating the stock of a product via '[product_stock.update](http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalogInventory/cataloginventory_stock_item.update.html)' (or cataloginventory_stock_item.update)

my code looks like this:

```
$.soap({
        url: serverAdress,
        method: 'call',
        data: {
            sessionId: sessionID,
            resourcePath: 'product_stock.update',
            data: {
                productId: product.id.toString(),
                stockItemData: {
                    qty: qty.toString()
                }
            }
        },

        success: function (soapResponse) {
            alert("Success: " + soapResponse.toString());
        },

        error: function (SOAPResponse) {
            alert("Error: " + SOAPResponse.toString());
        }

    })
```

i have tried all combinations of arrays as arguments i could imagine, just can't get it to work. in addition i tried SKU as string and with appended " " empty space to overcome one known bug.

always returns "faultcode:101 product not exists"

where am i messing up my arguments?
thanks for any help!

Comment: Try changing productId to product

Comment: I am unable to get "sessionId" using login api. Can you help me with sample code for login api to get session id?
Here is my code:
`$.soap({
            url: "http://MAGENTO_INSTALLATION/api/soap/?wsdl=1",
            method: 'login',
            data: {
                username: 'xxxx',
                apiKey: 'xxxx'
            },
            success: function (soapResponse) {
                // print success
            },
            error: function (SOAPResponse) {
                // print error
            }
        });`
But always WSDL content is returned in response.